# How to Query in Sqllite database for Timestamp Column in Android with Content provider?

Tags: android, sqlite, timestamp

I have a database with timestamp column.
[transaction table of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDpkI.jpg)
I wanted to do query for today's date for which I wrote sql query like this

```
SELECT * from TransactionTable where transaction_date < datetime('now') 
AND transaction_date >= datetime('now','start of day') ORDER by transaction_date DESC
```

**It worked perfectly but when I include it in my Android App it returns 0 rows.**
here's how I added in my App.

```
String selection =  myContractClass.myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_TRANSACTION_DATE + "  < ?" + " AND "
                + myContractClass.myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_TRANSACTION_DATE + " >= ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { "datetime('now')" , "datetime('now','start of day')" };
        try
        {
            new FetchTransaction(selection,selectionArgs,"10").execute(myContractClass.myTransactionEntry.CONTENT_URI);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

where FetchTransaction Class is having constructor like this :

```
  public FetchTransaction(String selection,String[] args, String limit)
    {
    this.selection = selection;
    this.selectionArgs = args;
    this.limit = limit;
    }
```

and  doing this in doInBackground method:-

```
  c = getContentResolver().query(
                    myContractClass.myTransactionEntry.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
                            .appendQueryParameter(myContentProvider.QUERY_PARAMETER_LIMIT,limit).build(),
                    projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

for further investigation I am providing content provider details too:-

```
    case TRANSACTION:

                SQLiteQueryBuilder sqLiteQueryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
                sqLiteQueryBuilder.setTables(myTransactionEntry.TABLE_NAME + " INNER JOIN " + myDbEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ON " +  myTransactionEntry.TABLE_NAME + "."
                        +myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID + "=" +  myDbEntry.TABLE_NAME       + "." +myDbEntry._ID);
                //sqLiteQueryBuilder.setTables("TransactionTable  INNER JOIN Products ON TransactionTable.product_id_in_product_table = Products._ID");
                HashMap<String,String> columnprojection = new HashMap<String,String>();
               columnprojection.put(myTransactionEntry._ID , myTransactionEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + myTransactionEntry._ID );
              columnprojection.put(myDbEntry.TABLE_NAME+ "." + myDbEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME,  myDbEntry.TABLE_NAME       + "." +myDbEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME + " AS " + "PNAME");
                columnprojection.put(myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHANGED,myTransactionEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHANGED + " AS " + "QTY");
                columnprojection.put(myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_TRANSACTION_TYPE,myTransactionEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_TRANSACTION_TYPE + " AS " + "TTYPE");
                columnprojection.put(myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_TRANSACTION_DATE,myTransactionEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_TRANSACTION_DATE + " AS " + "TDATE");
                columnprojection.put(myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_ANYREMARK,myTransactionEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_ANYREMARK+ " AS " + "TREMARK");
                columnprojection.put(myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID, myTransactionEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID + " AS " + "PID");
                sqLiteQueryBuilder.setProjectionMap(columnprojection);

            c = sqLiteQueryBuilder.query(db,null,
                    selection,selectionArgs,null ,null,sortOrder,limit);
```

Where is the problem? Why it is returning 0 rows instead of today's data.
I guess the error is in selectionArgs but idk.

Comment: link to table's data  (https://ibb.co/7gKyffD)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are passing the SQLite functions as arguments. As such they will be enclosed as literals(Strings) and thus not recognised as the functions.

Your SQL when the arguments are bound will result in something like:-

`SELECT * from TransactionTable where transaction_date < 'datetime(''now'')'  AND transaction_date >= 'datetime(''now'',''start of day'')' ORDER by transaction_date DESC`

Pass no args as there aren't any and include the functions in the selection string.

So you'd have :-

```
String selection =  myContractClass.myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_TRANSACTION_DATE + "  < datetime('now')" + " AND "
            + myContractClass.myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_TRANSACTION_DATE + " >= datetime('now','start of day')";

....

c = sqLiteQueryBuilder.query(db,null,selection,null,null ,null,sortOrder,limit);
```

- ***Note** the above is in principle code, it has not been compiled or run and thus may contain errors.*

Comment: Sometime searching for solution we dive ourselves deep and forget basic stuffs , thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to do query for today's date

Assuming that there are no future transactions, there is no need to use any `?` placeholders and pass any parameters.

All you have to do is get the date only from your timestamp with the function `DATE()` and compare it to the token `CURRENT_DATE` which returns the current date:

```
String selection = "DATE(" + myContractClass.myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_TRANSACTION_DATE + ") = CURRENT_DATE";
```

or, simpler:

```
String selection = myContractClass.myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_TRANSACTION_DATE + " >= CURRENT_DATE";
```

and call `query()` with `null` for `selectionArgs`:

```
c = sqLiteQueryBuilder.query(db, null, selection, null, null, null, sortOrder, limit);
```

Comment: thanks @forpas , combining your's and mikeT I made it work.  Acutally, I had to use datetime function instead of date in selection string.

Comment: @Vivekgupta if you use `datetime(transaction_date)` the result is exactly the same as just `transaction_date` because `transaction_date` is already a timestamp (datetime).

Comment: I needed it to convert to localtime , otherwise the result is arbitrary.